# Documenting code snippets with \snippet in doxygen

Tags: c#, .net, doxygen

am trying to document a code snippet for an API I created using doxygen. Following the example on http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdsnippet

I have the following example snippet code, and I only want to have the code between the markers [Marker] on my documentation page. This code resides in GetValues.cs.

```
class example_GetValues : globalParams
{
//!     [Marker]    
public bool GetValues()
    {            
        bool retVal = false;
        try
        {
            Dvr.GetValues();
            retVal = true;
        }
        catch (Exception excp)
        {
            TraceLog.WriteLine("Error" + excp.ToString());
        }
        return retVal;
    }
//!     [Marker]
}
```

I call the above from another file apiList.cs, using the following:

```
/// <summary>
/// Info about the API    
/// </summary>
/// \snippet GetValues.cs Marker
```

I can see all the 'Info about the API' in my documentation, but only an empty box in place of the snippet.

Any clues on what is going wrong with generating the snippet using document, or if the `\snippet` command is used in a different way in C#?

Comment: \snippet example_GetValues.cs Marker should read \snippet GetValues.cs Marker. The \snippet needs a file name. I assume you have set the EXAMPLE_PATH and that all the documentation of appList.cs is shown (I had to add a \file to appList.cs and I also set EXTRACT_... to YES to get all the documentation). With the conditions set I do see the snippet.

Comment: Hi Albert, Can you share your doxygen settings? Yes, I have set the EXAMPLE_PATH to the directory containing the GetValues.cs file. The file name above was a typo, I fixed that. Thanks for catching that.

Comment: I revisited the example and the following setting were needed for me: Doxyfile EXAMPLE_PATH = ., in the file apiList.cs add /// \file, in the file GetValues.cs replace the lines: //!     [Marker] with //     [Marker].